# Salvar no banco de dados utilizando jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar os dados digitados em minha janela modal e setar ele no banco de dados. Abaixo segue as paginas.

listarUsuario.php

```
<div class = "conteudo">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div align="left" id="inserir">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Inserir
                        </button>
                    </div>

                                <!-- Listar cargos -->
                <legend>Relação de Cargos</legend>
                <?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>

                </div>
                <!-- Fim listar cargos -->

</div> <!-- FECHA CONTEUDO -->




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Novo Úsuario</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">            
        <div align="center">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="salvarUsuario.php" method="post" id="cadUsuario">
            <fieldset>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" name="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="input-large">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" name="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input-xlarge">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="TXT_SENHA_USUAR"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" name="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" type="password" placeholder="Senha" class="input-small">

              </div>
            </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#cadUsuario').submit()">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

salvarUsuario.php

```
<?php
    // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");

    $nome = isset($_POST['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR']) ? $_POST['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL']) ? $_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL'] : '';
    $senha = isset($_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR']) ? $_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR'] : '';


    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_USUARIOS (TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, TXT_SENHA_USUAR) VALUES";
    $query .=  "('$nome','$email','$senha')";

    //executando a query
    $inserir = mysql_query($query)
    or die(error());

    $response = array("success" => true);

    //fechando a conexao com o banco
    mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

O erro que está dando é que quando eu clico em salvar nao aparece nada, a pagina fica da mesma maneira. O que estou fazendo de errado.

----------------------------------x
Estou conseguindo salvar, porem quando faço por ajax, eu não consigo fazer com que funcione de jeito nenhum. Irei colocar o codigo para ver onde esotu errando.

listaUsuario.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#cadUsuario').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "salvarUsuario.php",
                data: null,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="cadUsuario">
            <fieldset>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" name="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="input-large">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" name="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input-xlarge">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="TXT_SENHA_USUAR"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" name="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" type="password" placeholder="Senha" class="input-small"> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>          
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="botao_cadUsuario">Salvar</button>
```

E a nova pagina de fazer realmente o cadastro está assim.

salvarUsuario.php

```
<?php
    // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");

    $nome = isset($_POST['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR']) ? $_POST['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL']) ? $_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL'] : '';
    $senha = isset($_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR']) ? $_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR'] : '';


    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_USUARIOS (TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, TXT_SENHA_USUAR) VALUES";
    $query .=  "('$nome','$email','$senha')";

    //executando a query
    $inserir = mysql_query($query)
    or die(error());

    $response = array("success" => true);

    //fechando a conexao com o banco
    mysql_close($conn);

    echo "Cadastrado com Sucesso!";

?>
```

Não é problema no sql, pois está funcionando perfeitamente, o negocio está que quando clico no botão salvar ele não reconhece que aquele botão é salvar.

Comment: procure ler sobre ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está misturando as coisas. O jQuery não deve ser **nunca** colocado no HTML inline, assim como o Vanilla JS, essa é uma prática horrível que deve ser evitada **ao máximo**. Você precisa fazer um *handle* no evento de clique do botão por um arquivo JavaScript separado, dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.btn.btn-primary').click(function() {
        $('#cadUsuario').submit();
    });
});
```

Recomendo que adicione um identificador ao botão que irá dar *submit* no formulário, assim a *query* fica menos genérica e você não corre o risco de outro botão semelhante ativar o evento. Ficando assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#botao_submit').click(function() {
        $('#cadUsuario').submit();
    });
});
```

---

Para fazer a requisição automaticamente sem a necessidade da página ser redirecionada/atualizada, é necessário o uso do AJAX ao invés do `submit()` no formulário. O código abaixo está bem simples porém funciona corretamente, você pode adaptá-lo de acordo com suas necessidades:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.btn.btn-primary').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "salvarUsuario.php",
          data: null,
          success: function(data) {
            // Coloque aqui as instruções para fechar o dialog
          },
          error: function(request, status, error) {
            // Aqui você trata um erro que possa vir a ocorrer
            // Exemplo:
            alert("Erro: " + request.responseText);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Como tinha lhe dito, recomendar dar um olhada [aqui](http://blog.rafaelalmeidatk.com/criando-requisicoes-ajax-com-jquery/) para entender melhor como o AJAX funciona.

Comment: se eu so alterar isto ja irá funcionar ?

Comment: fiz desta forma porem, não funcionou.

Comment: Aparentemente sim. Os valores serão inseridos no banco de dados corretamente caso seu arquivo de conexão esteja válido. Só lhe aviso que você não programou nenhum meio de resposta, então isso não irá acontecer.

Comment: Você tem o jQuery inserido em sua página? **O que** não funcionou? Sem informações não tem como ninguém te ajudar.

Comment: Ele cadastra no banco de dados, so que a pagina não da um refresh, ela vai para a pagina salvarUsuario.php e fica estatica, preciso que ela volte para a pagina aonde ela estava porem com o modal fechado.

Comment: Ah sim, você terá que trabalhar com AJAX para poder realizar esse tipo de ação sem sair ou dar *refresh* na página.

Comment: Tem alguma dica, ou tópico, ou vídeo, onde eu possa aprender mais sobre isto ? Estou tendo muita dificuldade nesta área e preciso de algo para enriquecer meu conhecimento, tem algo para indicar ?

Comment: Existem vários artigos na internet. A propósito, eu fiz um artigo bem básico sobre isso: http://blog.rafaelalmeidatk.com/criando-requisicoes-ajax-com-jquery/ Eu irei editar essa resposta com mais informações assim que possível, estou de saída agora.

Comment: dê mais uma olhadinha por favor.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues desculpe pela demora, só fiquei disponível agora. Dê uma olhada novamente na resposta e veja se entendeu.

Answer (score 1):

De início, debugue o código para ver se está indo corretamente o form.

```
<?php // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    var_dump('entrou no post'); // se passar daqui já é uma boa notícia.
    die();
    //se passar daqui, apague o var_dump e die acima.
        $nome = isset($_POST['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR']) ? $_POST['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR'] : '';
        $email = isset($_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL']) ? $_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL'] : '';
        $senha = isset($_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR']) ? $_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR'] : '';


        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_USUARIOS (TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, TXT_SENHA_USUAR) VALUES";
        $query .=  "('$nome','$email','$senha')";

        //executando a query
        $inserir = mysql_query($query)
        or die(error());
        //var_dum($inserir); //debuga seu SQL

        $response = array("success" => true);

        //fechando a conexao com o banco
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
?>
```